Ubuntu How to change the username PGAdmin tries to use to login
I uninstalled Postgresql and PGAdmin4 from ubuntu and installed them back but, now, when I open PGAdmin and click on servers/local, it requests for the password of a user no longer exists and there's no option to choose another user. How can I set PGAdmin to use another user to login?


Either delete the old registration and create a new one, or just edit the old one to provide the new info.
